# Is there a standard/accepted way for a plugin library to identify its location on disk?

Tags: c, shared-library

I am working on a C program that has a plugin architecture. We build and package both `.rpm` and `.deb` packages.

Some plugins have additional non-binary resources, such as image files, or script files that only apply to that plugin. Those additional resources are in the put in the same directory as the plugin's `.so` file. So the plugins need to know where they are located on disk, and in their same directory, be able to open their associated files.

Is there a standard, or at least more-or-less idiomatic, way of doing this?

Note that I am wary of hardcoding paths such as `/usr/lib/<foo>/plugins`, especially since some distros like to use `/usr/lib64` vs `/usr/lib`.

Additionally, during development, the program (and/or plugins) are not installed in standard locations. They are executed out of a source code subdirectory in the user's home folder, and the plugin folders are in a slightly different relative location from the binary under development in these cases.

**Edit**: For a concrete example, the source tree for project `foo` has a `plugins` directory. Some standard plugins that are shipped with with `foo` are maintained in the `plugins` directory. One of the plugins, `pyconsole`, relies on `foo_pycon.py`, which is also in `plugins\pyconsole\` directory.

During development, I might have several copies of the repo in my home directory, for different work on different branches. One working copy might be in `~\src\foo_branch\`.

I invoke that locally-built instance of `foo` by: `~\src\foo_branch\release_x86_64\bin\foo`. `foo` locates all the plugins in a relative subdirectory, including `~\src\foo_branch\release_x86_64\lib\plugins\pyconsole.so`.

Is there a standard or idiomatic way for this particular instance of `pyconsole.so` to know where it is located, so it can open and use its own `foo_pycon.py`?

Note that when installed via packages, the relative paths are/might be different. Where as `/usr/bin/foo` is the location of the installed binary, we install our plugins under `/usr/lib[64]/foo/plugins`.

Comment: seems to me that graphics, sound files, etc. would belong under /usr/share/appname and not in /usr/lib

Comment: @ivanivan Probably right. I think that's probably acceptable if I modify the packaging for existing plugins. But what about script files, such as custom Python scripts to initialize and setup the custom built-in Python interpreter that is added by a plugin? The Python script is checked into the source repo, and is very much "part" of the plugin.

Comment: You coudl go with something like /usr/share/appname/plugins/pluginname and put EVERYthing in there, with corresponding ./lib ./share etc. directories for each pluginname directory.  But at this point I'd say read over the FHS for the "ideal" location and follow that practice as best you can.

Comment: Libraries could be stashed as `/usr/lib/appname/...` (mailman does this) or `/usr/libexec/appname/...` (various things on RedHat use this) but I'd definitely put the images and whatnot under a `share` dir, not `lib`. You'll probably also need an `ENV` for the user override.

Comment: I agree that things should go in standard places to conform with FHS. But, that still doesn't solve everything. _During_ development, coders aren't going to manually and continually put _files (scripts, mostly) actively being developed_ in a "standard" location. So the question remains, is there a standard or idiomatic way for a plugin to know where its own binary resides?

Comment: @scottbb The suggestion by thrig, to have an environment variable available for overrides, seems like a fairly solid approach to me